# how to get absolute path of a file using string

Tags: java

Im trying to get an absolute path of file but the filename is string. Following is my code:

```
Path path = Paths.get(filename[1]);
    Path p= path.toAbsolutePath();

     File file = new File(p.toString());
```

For example Im trying to access lab7.html which has following absolute path

```
D:\software engineering\5 semester\web engineering\lab7
```

but using the above approach it gives me following path

```
 D:\lab7.html
```

because of which Filenotfound exception is raised

Comment: You want to debug / print the value of `filename[1]`. If it's just the file name + extension, it'll be relative to the class being executed. Hence the `toAbsolutePath` will return a non-existing file.

Comment: Yes it does have an extension has well

Comment: Why use `File` if you use `Path`? It's like using an ox cart when you have a car.

Comment: Then what is the alternative solution. If I do it like this : file f= new file(string);   and f.getAbsolutePath()... it returns an error

Comment: And for that matter, `Path` has a `.toFile()` method that you could use directly to do it.

Comment: @Mena tried that too. Problem is that it is not traversing its subdirectories

Comment: @FatalError tried that. Its not for path its for File

Comment: @puffles: As in, `File file = p.toFile();`?

Comment: How are you running the program? When `Path` resolves relative location to an absolute one it (usually) uses user dir/`pwd`/location you start the script/program as a current location. If your run program from `D:\` it's perfectly reasonable to expect that result would be `D:\lab7.html`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toAbsolutePath() talks about *default system directory* - check which one is default in your case.